# nix-copy-closure "command not found" error

Tags: bash, ssh, nixos

I'm trying to copy a Nix closure to my server, using

```
nix-copy-closure user@server.com /nix/store/somelonghash-programname
```

but I get

```
bash: nix-store: command not found
error: cannot connect to 'user@server.com'
```

When I login to the server with `ssh user@server.com` I can run `nix-store --version` and it works.

Both machines are running Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 3):

I found a workaround for this, from [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/23650).  The script for making the Nix commands available is sourced in `~/.profile`.  I think the reason they are not available with `nix-copy-closure` that ssh doesn't source `~/.profile` when commands are run non-interactively.  Adding

```
command=". ~/.profile; if [ -n \"$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND\" ]; then eval \"$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND\"; else exec \"$SHELL\"; fi"
```

before my ssh public key (and on the same line) in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the server solves the problem for me.

I would still like to know why `nix-copy-closure` isn't handling this automatically.